# Iconography for Beginning and End points?

Tags: icons, iconography

I'd like to create icons for the endpoints of a process, but I'm not sure what to use.

Going with "A" and "B" comes to mind as that's a familiar reference (e.g. "the shortest distance from A to B") but I would prefer to leave that as a last resort.

Any good alternatives out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your talking about a process, you might also consider borrowing from [BPMN](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Notation)

[image: Minimal process that strarts and ends]

Comment: This works great! Adding an English link as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation

Answer (score 7):

The following type of symbols often work quite adequately for beginning and end of a process.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For end point, the black and white blocked flag as seen in in motorsports comes to mind. I think most users will associate it with "finish".

Beginning point is a little harder. How about a green traffic light or a green flag?

[image]

(This is how TomTom shows start and end point in thei navigation app)

Comment: In my mind, this flags are associated with an itinerary.

Comment: A car race does not have a real itinerary either. In fact, start and finish are physically on the exact same place. In my mind, I see it as "start of race" and "end of race", in other words, a moment in time rather than a place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Alpha and Omega symbols.

Comment: You should raise your concerns about this site's UX in a separate thread on Meta.

Comment: Has already been done. Suggestion is to use a workaround: add HTML comment. Which also sucks.

Comment: @snufflemuffin In the context of answering this question - can we just leave it that perhaps you could use Alpha and Omega symbols? ;-)

Comment: would people recognize the alpha and omega symbols?

Comment: Alpha and Omega are awesome symbols with great meaning...but I doubt many typical English users would recognize them. They'd be awesome icons for a God of War game, however.

Answer (score 0):

How about either of these? [image]